# socket io for java maven eclipse is not working because it's not recognizing socket io

Tags: sockets, io

this is my dependency

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>a</groupId>
  <artifactId>a</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
    <artifactId>socket.io-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>


this is my client  (main)
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        socket = IO.socket("http://145.24.222.151::8085");
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

          public void call(Object... args) {
            Socket.emit("foo", "hi");
            Socket.disconnect();
          }

        }).on("event", new Emitter.Listener() {

          public void call(Object... args) {}

        }).on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {

          public void call(Object... args) {}

        });
        Socket.connect();



    }
}
```

it is not recognzigng any of the socket functions only like 2 i already did maven clean maven install and i tried to shut down and open eclipse again its not doing anything anyone know why?
the errors i get are:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    socket cannot be resolved to a variable
    IO cannot be resolved
    socket cannot be resolved
    Socket cannot be resolved to a variable
    Emitter cannot be resolved to a type
    socket cannot be resolved
    socket cannot be resolved
    Emitter cannot be resolved to a type
    The method call(Object...) of type new Listener(){} must override a superclass method
    Socket cannot be resolved to a variable
    Emitter cannot be resolved to a type
    The method call(Object...) of type new Listener(){} must override a superclass method
    socket cannot be resolved

```
at client.main(client.java:3)
```